# Line integral over a vector field with 2 coordinates?

Tags: calculus, integration

Find the work done by the force field $F = xi + yj + (xz − y)k$ to move a particle along the curve with parametric equations $r(t) =< t^2
, 2t, 4t^3
 >, 0 ≤ t ≤ 1,$ from $A(0, 0, 0)$ to $B(1, 2, 4)$.

$$\int F dr $$

What is the point of the from A(0, 0, 0) to B(1, 2, 4) information? I already have the vector field and the parametric equation of the curve.

If I compute dr(t) then take the dot product of F.dr, then take the integral of that I will get the work, no?

where **F** = x**i** + y**j** + (xz − y)**k**

$r(t) =< t^2, 2t, 4t^3 >, 0 ≤ t ≤ 1$

Comment: The information is just given as confirmation that those are the endpoints on the curve for the specified parametric interval, I believe.

Comment: so F(r(t) =  t^2i + 2tj + (t^2*4t^3 − 2t)k and the dot product of that with r'(t) would be the setup of this problem.

Comment: Yes:  it just looks to be a polynomial integrand, so there's nothing complicated here; the value is a ratio of small integers.